# Application of the Intermediate Value theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and that $f(0) = f(2)$. Then $\exists$ $x,$ $y \in [0,2]$ such that $|y - x| = 1$ and that $f(x) = f(y)$.

Let $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$ on $[0,1]$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and hence $g$ enjoys the intermediate value property! Now notice $$g(0) = f(1) - f(0)$$ $$g(1) = f(2) - f(1)$$
Therefore $$ g(0)g(1) = -(f(0) - f(1))^2 < 0$$
since $f(0) = f(2)$. Therefore, there exists a point $x$ in $[0,1]$ such that $g(x) = 0$ by the intermediate value theorem. Now, if we pick $y = x + 1$, i think the problem is solved.

I would like to ask you guys for feedback. Is this solution correct? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You might have $g(0)g(1)=0$ and not $<0$, but then $x=0$, $y=1$ is a solution.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good!

It is enough to write $g(1)=-g(0)$..

And, as Hagen commented, you only forgot to mention the case when already $f(0)=f(1)$, but then it is readily done.